# Using array_multisort to sort integer ascending and sort corresponding string accordingly (php)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

Using `array_multisort`, how can I sort prices from lowest to highest and then use that sorting order to sort its corresponding title?

**Arrays**

```
$pricearray = array(4.00, 56.99, 3.19);
$headerarray = array('four', 'fifty-six', 'three');
```

**Desired Output**

```
$pricearray = array(3.19, 4.00, 56.99);
$headerarray = array('three', 'four', 'fifty-six');
```

**My Attempt**

```
array_multisort($headerarray, $pricearray, SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: why do you have 2 arrays and not just one? `array('three'=>3.19, 'four'=>4.00,'fifty-six'=> 56.99);`

Comment: There is another part of this code that requires me to have two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort `$pricearray` ascending (the default) and `array_multisort` will sort `$headerarray` with it:

```
array_multisort($pricearray, $headerarray);
```

To specify the order use it as the argument after the array:

```
array_multisort($pricearray, SORT_ASC, $headerarray);
```

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) where it states that some arguments can be swapped or omitted:

> **array1_sort_order** The order used to sort the previous array argument.
>   Either SORT_ASC to sort ascendingly or SORT_DESC to sort descendingly.
>
> This argument can be swapped with array1_sort_flags or omitted
>   entirely, in which case SORT_ASC is assumed.
>
> **array1_sort_flags** Sort options for the previous array argument:
>
> This argument can be swapped with array1_sort_order or omitted
>   entirely, in which case SORT_REGULAR is assumed.